# Someone can confirm if Quadro P5000 works fine with EEVEE?

Tags: rendering

I didn't find if Quadro P5000 works fine, at least more or less as a GTX1080 or even as a GTX1070, rendering with EEVEE. I'm afraid of more incompabilities, bugs or crashing or things like that than a GTX10xx series... Have I nothing to be afraid of ? could anyone confirm me if EEVEE works fine with this graphic card ?

One of my costumers can only get a P5000 in time for a presentation with EEVEE.

THANKS A LOT ! Happy blending to all !